# Can the same person have multiple accounts?

Tags: discussion, user-accounts, specific-user, display-names, multiple-accounts

I have noticed two users namely [Justim Bieber](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/81087/justim-bieber) and [Justen Bieber](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/77402/justen-bieber) who I suspect are the same person.

Is this allowed and encouraged especially when [one is commenting on the others posts](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/435119/if-q-is-prime-then-w-1qq2-3-is-a-composite-integer-iff-w-has-a-prime).

Comment: That is the same guy who had a myriad of political figures. Some where deleted, but apparently he opened more and is now into pop stars.

Comment: I would like to remind everyone that per our privacy agreement, moderators cannot confirm nor deny @picakhu's suspicion. And that in general we would prefer users to flag about specific users/questions and keep meta to more general/abstract discussions. Thank you.

Comment: The cross-interactions between these two accounts occur elsewhere as well, by the way.

Comment: This guy is the funniest person on MSE.

Comment: We've had Obama, Romney, Kim Jong Il, Rodman, Bieber...all commenting on each other's answers/questions almost exclusively. I still don't know if I find this very funny or very boring.

Comment: And I like how all of them say "Note: If you change one letter in my name, you will get my real one."

Comment: @Julien I recently saw [Kanye West](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3224909/proof-that-the-limit-superior-of-a-function-is-a-point-of-accumulation)  ^^ MSE will have Kim soon I guess..

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Multiple accounts are usually tolerated, but they are not allowed to interact at all. If you are e.g. just using a different account to ask a question anonymously, this is allowed as long as you don't vote on it, don't circumvent any rate limit on it and don't interact with that account in any other way.

Interacting with your own accounts, and trying to give the impression that they belong to different users is not allowed.

Comment: but there is a way to prevent cases like this one?

Comment: @user75086 Yes, but it would require more than an e-mail confirmation.

Comment: Have you reviewed the two accounts and found that they are not the same person?

Comment: @Thomas I'm not a moderator on MSE, you have to ask one of your own moderators or the SE team for that.

Comment: @MadScientist, is there anyway to detect voting fraud committed with use of VPN? It's not that I intend do so but to know.

Comment: @Edit There are quite a few different ways to detect voting fraud, and using a VPN or Tor is not sufficient to evade detection.