# Can I create several other users for specific purposes?

Tags: discussion, user-accounts, multiple-accounts

Can I have more than one user? Is there a limit?

They'll have decent questions I think, but may stay dormant for a while...

Comment: IOW, we are still in search of a legitimate reason.

Comment: See also: [Can the same person have multiple accounts?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10155)

Comment: @Did I guess that it would be better to have a separate question about "What are legitimate reasons to have multiple accounts?" than to discuss it here in comments. Some discussion about possible reasons can be found in [these comments on meta.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35593/whats-the-policy-about-having-multiple-user-accounts#comment226267_35607). In the past I have asked our mods about [separate account for testing purposes](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20352/conversation/creating-multiple-accounts-for-testing-purposes). But I agree that two accounts are unusual.

Comment: @MartinSleziak  The title of this question is **"Can I create several other users for specific purposes?"** Unless the question lists such reasons, I default to "no".  Telling the asker what not to is a stab in the dark at the vague category "specific purposes.  So no, I think a separate question would be a duplicate of this post.  Asker asks question pertaining to multiple accounts for different purposes.  The asker gives no context, no articulation of the  "different purposes" s/he has in mind.

Comment: @amWhy Obviously, we read the question differently. I understand the question as: "Is it allowed to have separate accounts?" And as you can see from the answer and from the other linked threads, the answer is yes, it is allowed.

Comment: @Did FWIW it appears to be somewhat common for users on MO to ask questions (at least those they perceive as possibly not so great) with an account other than their main (often real-name) account. I do not say this is a great state of affairs, but it appears to be accepted their, and I see nothing inherently wrong with it. Quite many people are worried to "look ignorant" in public.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is allowed to have several accounts as long as you do nothing with those accounts that in essence you could not also do with a single one.

Some examples of things not to do:

1. Do not use a new account to evade a suspension or ban.
2. Do not vote for posts of your other accounts. Best, try not interact with posts of your other accounts at all.
3. Do not use another account for some action once you hit a rate-limit on the main account for this action (especially voting).
4. Do not use several accounts to vote multiple times on the same post. (This can  be tricky to track; a solution is to vote only with one account.)

However it seems your intent is to use them just to ask questions. This should be mostly fine. (Except of course if you should use them to get around a question ban or rate limit, or other shady actions, like asking anew with another account a minor variant of a question of yours that got closed earlier.)

Comment: I'm puzzled.  "It is allowed to have several accounts as long as you do nothing with those accounts that in essence you could not also do with a single one."  Then one account should suffice, yes?  And since the asker refuses to discuss for what purposes s/he is asking in terms of holding multiple accounts, it seems any legitimate reason can be done in one account.  Not so when the reasons for having more than one account are illegitimate.  The question remains: